# Number search without using array

Tags: java

How to write a Java program to get a number from user,from that remove odd numbers and display even numbers without using an array(Ex: i/p:2345678, o/p:2468)

I can do with array.

```
public class NumberSearch {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int n[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        System.out.println("Even number");
        for(int i=0;i<n.length;i++){
            if(n[i]%2==0){
                System.out.println(n[i]);
            }
        } 
}}
```

But i want to do with 123456 numbers like this without using an array.

Comment: How do you plan to store the numbers?  You could use a String.

Comment: Do you wish to input a string, extract it to an array, convert the strings to integers and then evaluate if they're even or not? Is the maximum number a 9?

Comment: "_from that remove odd numbers_", you mean digits instead of numbers here? So an input like `6278391508` would result in `62808`?

Comment: Hint: be clear about wording. You want ONE number 123456, and then for each DIGIT within that number 1, 2, 3, ... you want to decide whether that "single digit as number" would be odd/even. And that leads to your answer: dont think "number", but "string". Then walk that string, and for each character decide whether the corresponding digit is odd/even.

Comment: Get a number as integer not a string.Without using array display even numbers and remove odd numbers. Example int n = 123456; process it without using an array and display 246

Comment: Most important for me are the preconditions to meet: where does the data come from(what is the input) and where should it go(what is the expected output. I understood; only even numbers - but how are they received resp consumed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go character by character and only add the even ones to the output String.

```
String input = "2345678";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if(Character.getNumericValue(c) % 2 == 0) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}
String output = sb.toString();

System.out.println(output);
```

Outputs:

```
2468
```

- I am using a `StringBuilder` as it is more efficient in loops.
- You need to use `Character.getNumericValue` to transform a `char` into its numeric value

Answer (score 2):

Parse int input to string, replace all odd digits, and print output (if needed parse back to int):

```
    int input  = 123456;
    String str = String.valueOf(input);
    String res = str.replaceAll("[13579]", "");
    System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Similar as how I would do it, but with `1|3|5|7|9` replaced with `[13579]`. :)

Comment: See we have to get an input at run time. I specified to understand what to do.

Comment: @sugani I would make that a separate question.